# Mobile screen issue with All Months' Expenses expansion and layout in Expense Tracker dashboard

Tags: javascript, css

I am developing an Expense Tracker dashboard using HTML, CSS, Python (Flask) and JavaScript. On desktop screens, everything works fine, including the "All Months' Expenses" section. However, when I switch to a mobile screen, I encounter two issues with the "All Months' Expenses" section.

Expanding Without Clicking: On mobile screens, all the month data is expanded by default without requiring any click. In contrast, on desktop screens, the expansion works correctly, and clicking on a month expands its details.

Vertical Layout Issue: The month data appears horizontally in a single row on mobile screens, making it difficult to read. On desktop screens, the layout is correct, with each month's data vertically aligned.

For reference, here is the relevant JavaScript code that handles the expansion:

```
// Function to handle click on Last 7 Days date div
function handleLast7DaysClick(date) {
  const expensesDetails = document.getElementById(`expenses-details-${date}`);
  expensesDetails.style.display = expensesDetails.style.display === "none" ? "block" : "none";
}

// Function to handle click on All Months' month div
function handleMonthExpandClick(monthDiv) {
  const expensesDetails = monthDiv.nextElementSibling;
  expensesDetails.style.display = expensesDetails.style.display === "none" ? "block" : "none";
}

// Load functions
loadTodayExpenses(userId);
loadLast7DaysExpenses(userId);
loadAllMonthsExpenses(userId);
```

the // Function to handle click on Last 7 Days date div works completely fine

I want to achieve the same functionality on mobile screens as on desktop screens, where the "All Months' Expenses" data is collapsed by default and can be expanded by clicking on a specific month. Additionally, I want the data to be displayed vertically for each month on mobile screens.

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve these issues would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Could you include the CSS and HTML?